# Wordpress - Filtering post content before publishing

Tags: wordpress

I'm posting to a Wordpress blog using an email and I want to filter everything before the [title shortcode. I've been trying a few things but no luck. This is what I have:

```
<?php
function filter_handler( $data , $postarr ) {
// do something with the post data
$post_content = $postarr['post_content'];

strstr($post_content, '[title');

}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'filter_handler', '99', 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
function changePost($data, $postarr) {

  $data['post_content'] = strstr( $postarr['post_content'], '[title' );
return $data;
}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','changePost','99',2);
```